# Import SQL table from active connection in R using odbc

Tags: r, sql-server

I have connect Microsoft SQL Server 15 on Windows with a DSN name and i can see this connection in the connection window in Rstudio as the picture shows [image]

But i want to take a specific table from this database AdventureWorks2019 -> Sales -> CreditCard for example ?

What command should i use in order to appear this table as a data frame or tibble in R and play with this data frame ?

I can what the table includes in the view script as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a SQL Query and execute it.
You can use the `odbc::dbGetQuery()` function.

Try this code :

```
my_dataframe <- odbc::dbGetQuery(conn = con, "SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM Sales.CreditCard")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and knowledge.The right sql query though that worked is the ` `SELECT * FROM Sales.CreditCard`

Comment: All right, I edited